# converting list to dictionary in Python using zip or dict function

Tags: python, dictionary

After many attempts I was able to get the code below to index specific columns and rows for a given specific csv file. Now I would like to convert the code below into a dictionary, I read the documentation on dict and zip, however I'm still not clear...

CSV file contains 500 records and columns A:L corresponding to the headers below:

first_name, last_name, company, address, city, county, state, zip, phone1, phone2, email, web

```
import csv

f= open('us-500.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(f)              # use list or next
rows = list(reader)
for row in rows[0:20]:
    print "".join(row[8])
```

Comment: When you say "convert to a dictionary", what do you want the keys and values to be?

Comment: Also, your code is pretty misleading. The thing you call `columns` is actually a list of _rows_, each of which is itself a list of columns. So you're printing out column 8 from each of the first 20 rows. And, since that's already a string, the `"".join` is just a really inefficient way to make a new copy of the same string. Maybe if you can give us a few lines of sample data and the desired output, it'll be easier to understand what you want.

Comment: Do you want one dictionary item for each row, or one for each column?

Comment: You limit processing to the first 20 rows. Is that part of the specification? `list(reader)` reads the entire file which may include many more lines than you want.

Comment: if you add a snippet if the input and expected output it will make what you are trying to do a lot more transparent

Comment: I edited the source code to reflect rows instead of columns thanks for pointing that out. I need a dictionary item for each column in order to establish column phone1 as a primary key and reference it from a different class. The 20 limitation is not part of the specification, I was testing different scenarios.

Comment: @user3724235: Please edit the question to explain (or, better, show) the desired output instead of just trying to describe it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT  --> Based on the asker's comment, I think this is more what is wanted (using DictReader makes this much simpler):

```
import csv
with open('c:\us-500.csv', 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    address_book = {}
    for row in reader:
        address_book[row['phone1']] = row
```

Gives a dictionary for the file with the primary key as the 8th column "phone1".  Access values like this.

```
address_book['555-1212']['first_name'] 
address_book['978-3425']['email']
```

Edit2 --> Removing the original answer now.  Basically it was re-implementing the DictReader functionality.

Comment: If this is what you want, just use `csv.DictReader`.

Comment: Not familiar with DictReader.  Could you update my code to show that?

Comment: OK i checked it out and updated it and I think I now understand what the asker wanted too.

Comment: Your entire original loop can be replaced by just `myDictList = list(csv.DictReader(f))`. You obviously understand that now, because your second program uses it to great effect, but the first program isn't really necessary.

Comment: I implemented the first edit, it worked fine, I'll give the edit a shot in a bit, and will post results. Thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a wild guess at what you want.

You have a CSV file with, say, 10 columns.

You want a dictionary that uses column 8 of each row as the keys, and the whole row (that is, a list of all of the columns) as the corresponding values.*

So, instead of `list(reader)`, which just gives you a list of rows, you want this:

```
d = {row[8]: row for row in reader}
```

Or, if you're using, say, Python 2.5 and don't have dictionary comprehensions:

```
d = dict((row[8], row) for row in reader)
```

So, given this input file:

```
John, Smith, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
Ed, Jones, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100
```

You'd get this dictionary:

```
{'8': ['John', 'Smith', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
 '80': ['Ed', 'Jones', '20', '30', 40', '50', '60', '70', '80', '90', '100']}
```

---

<sub>* This assumes that the column 8 values are unique. Otherwise, this wouldn't make sense at all. You might instead want, say, a multi-dict, mapping each column-8 value to the list of all rows that have that column-8 value, or a dict mapping each column-8 value to a "multi-row" that zips together each of the column values of each of the rows that have that column-8 value, or… who knows what. All of these are pretty easy to write once you understand the basic idea and know which one you want.</sub>

Comment: This overwrites duplicate keys - which may be what the OP wants, but worth pointing out.

Comment: the OP seems to want the first 20 rows, your code uses every row

Comment: This really is a wild guess at what the OP wants, and I'm just hoping that if it's close, it'll teach him enough to be able to apply it to his actual problem; I'm not trying to give him code that he can just drop into some program we can't see and use on some data that we can't see and magically get the right answer…

Comment: Column 8 "phone1" is a unique identifier, the first 20 rows is irrelevant. In column 8 I'm looking to combine or group the exchange portion of "phone1" the middle 3 numbers. This would indicate they live in the same geographical area or town. I used Pandas prior in order to do this however it abstracts a lot of the thought process away which is why I want to do it this way.

Comment: @user3724235: I still don't understand what you're doing after that explanation. Again, please edit the question to be a complete question, including input and desired output. Also, please look at [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26412859/908494) and tell me if I guessed better over there.

Answer (score 0):

if you can get your data into two lists,(that are in the proper order that you want them in) then you are ready to convert to dictionarys.

```
>>> list_1 = ['pie','farts','boo']
>>>
>>> list_2 = ['apple','stanky','scary']
>>>
>>> dict(zip(list_1,list_2))
{'boo': 'scary', 'farts': 'stanky', 'pie': 'apple'}
>>>
>>> dict(zip(list_2,list_1))
{'apple': 'pie', 'stanky': 'farts', 'scary': 'boo'}
>>>
```

the zip command is kinda cool because it turns two lists into one list that has smaller lists inside of it,

```
>>> list(zip(list_1,list_2))
[('pie', 'apple'), ('farts', 'stanky'), ('boo', 'scary')]
```

then you just convert that into a dict

```
>>> dict(zip(list_1,list_2))
{'boo': 'scary', 'farts': 'stanky', 'pie': 'apple'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict` comprehension.

```
list1  = range(10)
list2 = range(20)
a = {k: v for k, v in zip(list1, list2)}
print a
```

Even can use `dict()` method.

```
b = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

output in both case is:-

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it sounds like what you're asking for is something like this:

- A list of rows.
- One or more "index" multi-dicts, that map the values from a particular column to a set of row numbers that have that value.

A "multi-dict" is just a dict mapping keys to some kind of collection, like a set or list. You can build one very easily by using `defaultdict`.

You can get each row number together with its list of values using the `enumerate` function.

So, let's build a couple of indices on your data:

```
import collections
import csv

f= open('us-500.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(f)              # use list or next
rows = list(reader)

phone1_index = collections.defaultdict(set)
phone2_index = collections.defaultdict(set)
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    phone1_index[row[8]].add(i)
    phone2_index[row[9]].add(i)
```

(Note that this really isn't quite the same as an index in a typical database—it's just as good for finding all rows `where phone1 == ?`, but not helpful for `where phone1 < ?`.)

---

But really, there's no reason to think in terms of indices. If you just store the rows themselves inside the dicts, you're not wasting any space; you can have two references to the same object in Python without having to copy all the data.

There is a minor technical problem, in that rows are lists, and therefore mutable, and therefore can't be stored in sets. But you probably don't actually *want* them to be mutable, they just happen to come out that way, so you can use tuples instead:

```
f= open('us-500.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(f)              # use list or next
phone1_map = collections.defaultdict(set)
phone2_map = collections.defaultdict(set)
for row in reader:
    row = tuple(row)
    phone1_map[row[8]].add(row)
    phone2_map[row[9]].add(row)
```

---

While we're at it, this looks like a good job for `namedtuple`:

```
header = 'first_name, last_name, company, address, city, county, state, zip, phone1, phone2, email, web'
Row = collections.namedtuple('Row', header.split(', '))

f= open('us-500.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(f)              # use list or next
phone1_map = collections.defaultdict(set)
phone2_map = collections.defaultdict(set)
for row in reader:
    row = Row(row)
    phone1_map[row.phone1].add(row)
    phone2_map[row.phone2].add(row)
```

So, now if you want to find the last name of everyone whose `phone1` or `phone2` is `1.555.555.1212`:

```
matches = phone1_map['1.555.555.1212'] | phone2_map['1.555.555.1212']
names = {match.name for match in matches}
```